# set cookie with 3 values, and then extract the 3 values when reading

Tags: php, variables, cookies, remember-me

im working on a remember me function and need to do e.g:

```
setcookie(
    "cookie",
"$userid, $token, $date",
time() + (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60)
);
```

I then want to be able to read the cookie and assign each value to a php variables:

```
$user id =
$token =
$date =
```

Any help? i have found a few examples but they dont work.

P.S. Ignore the lack of security. Im making this work and then creating all the hashing etc later.

EDIT:

Found this:

```
setcookie("acookie", $username . "," . $userid);
```

But cant get it working with a 3rd variable

Comment: You need encryption, not just hashing :)

Comment: Go ahead and get the encryption/hashing/protection out of the way now, that way you don't forget later. All it takes is one mistake ;)

Comment: the security side will come once the setting and detection of the cookie works :) site is still in development so no danger. First remember me / auto login i've done so trying it simple as possible to understand.

Comment: Understandable, just head my words: One mistake is all it takes, and these auto login forms are especially easy to screw up. BOO!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution 1

You could do something like this (if you really want just *one* cookie):

```
$cookie_val = $userid . ':' . $token . ':' . $date; 
// Make sure the values don't contain ":" or change to other 
// character that the values don't contain

setcookie("acookie", $cookie_val, time() + (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60));
```

Then, on the page where you're checking the cookie values, you could do this:

```
$cookie_arr = explode(':', $_COOKIE['acookie']);

$user id = $cookie_arr[0];
$token = $cookie_arr[1];
$date = $cookie_arr[2];
```

## Solution 2

This solution is much easier and I recommend that you use this. Just make three cookies, like `$_COOKIE['user_id']`, `$_COOKIE['token']` and `$_COOKIE['date']` and then call them simply by those names when you need to check their values.

```
// Create cookie
setcookie("user_id", $user_id, time() + (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60));

// Check cookie
$user_id = $_COOKIE['user_id'];
```

And so on...

Answer (score 2):

As far as your cookies go, once they are set appropriately you can access them via the $_COOKIE superglobal, similar to how you would use $_GET and/or $_POST.